# cannot add second FK : got error can't create table'.jobstatus\#sql-32c_12f2f.frm' (errno:150)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

```
     CREATE TABLE `job` (
    `jobId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `jobcode` varchar(25) default NULL,
    `jobname` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `location` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `budget` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
    `year_type` varchar(100) default NULL,
    `worklineId` int(11) default NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`jobId`),
     KEY `NewIndex` (`worklineId`),
     FOREIGN KEY (`worklineId`) REFERENCES `workline` (`worklineId`)
     ) TYPE=InnoDB;

     CREATE TABLE `subjob` (
    `subjobId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `subjobcode` varchar(25) default NULL,
    `subjobname` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `subjobbudget` int(11) unsigned default NULL,
    `jobgoal_date` date default '0000-00-00',
    `jobId` int(11) default NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`subjobId`),
     KEY `NewIndex` (`jobId`),
     FOREIGN KEY (`jobId`) REFERENCES `job` (`jobId`)
     ) TYPE=InnoDB;

     CREATE TABLE `contract` (
    `contractId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `contractcode` varchar(25) default NULL,
    `price` int(11) unsigned default NULL,
    `contractprice` int(11) unsigned default NULL,
    `company` varchar(50) default NULL,
    `signdate` date default '0000-00-00',
    `begindate` date default '0000-00-00',
    `enddateplan` date default '0000-00-00',
    `note` text,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`contractId`)
     ) TYPE=InnoDB;


     CREATE TABLE `subjob_contract` (
    `subjobcontractId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `status` varchar(11) default NULL,
    `contractId` int(11) default NULL,
    `subjobId` int(11) default NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`subjobcontractId`),
     KEY `NewIndex` (`contractId`),
     KEY `NewIndex2` (`subjobId`),
     FOREIGN KEY (`contractId`) REFERENCES `contract` (`contractId`)
     ) TYPE=InnoDB
```

I m using mysql front 3.2 to manage database,I can add first fk but when i add second fk i got an error following this :
sql execution error #1005. response from the database: can't create table'.jobstatus#sql-32c_12f2f.frm' (errno:150). i already define the new index for fk subjobId reference to subjob table what could be the possibility of this error? thank you

Comment: where is jobstatus table used here? describe the jobstatus table also here.

Comment: Where is your job table. I was trying to execute your table schema step by step and found problem in `FOREIGN KEY (`jobId`) REFERENCES `job` (`jobId`)`. share your job table

Comment: @Sami : any problem with my job table?

Comment: Again you job table had a foreign key. i ignored that and executed remaining on sqlfiddle, it executed. So whats your problem now? Get error while adding rows or making tables?

Comment: @Sami my problem is at table subjob_contract. I cant add 2 fk. i can add 1 fk only. when i add contractId as my Fk first, it can but i cannot add subjobId as my second Fk. they i try again i add subjobId as my first Fk, it can but i cannot add contractId as my second Fk

Comment: @shushu You can check the link given in my answer. I have used both foreign keys there.

Comment: Add the definition for "jobstatus".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the datatype and size of the **subjobId** column on primary table and referenced table. both must be same than it will allow you to create foreign key.

Comment: yaa they are same type and size, but its wondering, i just cannot add for the second FK. when i try to add subjobId first, it can then i cannot add contractId for the second FK. so i can conclude that it has the error when i add for the second FK

Comment: No we can add more FKs as we need. Put your create table script of all tables related to this topic in your question. Check that the referenced table is empty or not.

Comment: i put the related table. please check for me, thank you in advance

Comment: I had tried in my server I am able to add FK through this statement:  ALTER TABLE `subjob_contract` ADD CONSTRAINT `subjob_contract_jq` FOREIGN KEY (`subjobId`) REFERENCES `subjob`(`subjobId`);  Check subjob_contract table is empty or not, if not than subjobid column must contain the values which subjob table has

Comment: Which version of MySQL you are using? I had done this on 5.1.62-community-log version

Comment: I m using mysql front 3.2. is it posible cos of software prob?

Comment: Check MySQL version from SELECT VERSION() query. Run Alter statement which I had already written in my previous comment. It eill allow you to create second FK.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: You can not refer that column/table which is not created yet. Try to execute tables having foreign keys after the referenced tables.

Obviously you should have consistency in datatypes of foreign key and referenced column as well

[Correct Execution Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c35ca). Also You should use `Engine=InnoDB` instead of `Type=InnoDB`

Comment: but its no proble using type instead of Engine when i add just only 1 FK in the table but anyway thank you